# State not updating but console.log fires when using a ref as dependency for React useEffect:

Tags: reactjs

I need to ensure that the playing cards are not dealt until the level checking logic in the `useEffect` has completed and is set to `false`.

I have read that using a ref for the `useEffect` dependency will stop it from firing however the `console.log` inside the `useEffect` fires on every render but the set State does not seem to set to true at all meaning that the cards are always dealt because the state is never “true”.

Additionally, the `useEffect` with just the `checkingLevel` in its dependency never fires. It appears that the `checkingLevel` state remains `false` the entire time.

```
[...]
 const correctPhonemeCounts = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.gameState,
  );
  const correctPhonemeCountsRef = useRef(
    correctPhonemeCounts.correctPhonemeCounts,
  );
  const [checkingLevel, setCheckingLevel] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    correctPhonemeCountsRef.current = correctPhonemeCounts.correctPhonemeCounts;
  }, [correctPhonemeCounts.correctPhonemeCounts]);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('checking level');
    // Check if conditions for a level-up are met
    setCheckingLevel(true);

    const leveledData = levelData(currentLevelRef.current, spellingData);
    const levelUp = allPhonemesMastered(
      leveledData,
      correctPhonemeCountsRef.current,
    );

    if (levelUp) {
      dispatch(resetCorrectPhonemes());
      increaseLevel();
    }
    setCheckingLevel(false);
  }, [correctPhonemeCountsRef.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checkingLevel);
  }, [checkingLevel]);

  function handleDeal() {
    const leveledData = levelData(currentLevelRef.current, spellingData);
    const chosenSound = getPhoneme(
      leveledData,
      correctPhonemeCountsRef.current,
    );
    const cards = dealCards(chosenSound, leveledData);
    dispatch(setDealtCards(cards));
  }

  function handleCheckAnswer(card: any) {
  [...]

    const delayedDeal = () => {
      if (!checkingLevel) {
        handleDeal();
      } else {
        setTimeout(delayedDeal, 500);
      }
    };
```